# How to test textbox value against content of combobox

Tags: c#

I am trying to check if the value entered in the text box matches the content of the combobox or not.
But the condition is not met with me.

```
string Dnaam = tbAnimal.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < cmbAnimals.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Dnaam == (cmbAnimals.Items.GetItemAt(i).ToString()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is gevonden, het is de " + i + "item");
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is not gevonden");`
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `if` statement and check what's actually being compared, you might find that it's not what you were expecting

Comment: Without the input values, for all we know this code is correct, possibly just leading trailing space issues or casing.

Comment: As I don't know what framework you are using: The ToString() looks strange: Maybe you are converting an object to a string? what in most cases is not what you want.

Comment: See [How to write a good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: The answer to this problem is specific to the .Net or external library runtime. Please let us know the specific version, otherwise the answer will be ambiguous to new developers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string Dnaam = tbAnimal.Text;    
bool animalFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < cmbAnimals.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Dnaam == (cmbAnimals.Items.GetItemAt(i).ToString()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is gevonden, het is de " + i + "item");
        animalFound = true;
        break;
    }
}    
if (!animalFound)
    MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is not gevonden");`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time, it success with my but without the value of the bool, I will try this solution also.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from Combobox try this instead of `cmbAnimals.Items.GetItemAt(i).ToString()`.

```
string Dnaam = tbAnimal.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < cmbAnimals.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Dnaam == cmbAnimals.GetItemText(cmbAnimals.Items[i])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is gevonden, het is de " + i + "item");
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is not gevonden");`
```

You can also try `Contains` method.

```
if (cmbAnimals.Items.Contains(Dnaam))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Het Animal is gevonden, het is de " + i + "item");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and your time and your help :).
I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using [FindString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstring?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for case insensitive or [FindStringExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) methods are what you need in tangent with trimming the TextBox value.

This example will set the selected item in the ComboBox (yes you can use a MessageBox instead of selecting the item) if the text is found, otherwise inform the text was not located.

```
string searchFor = tbAnimal.Text.Trim();
int foundIndex = cmbAnimals.FindString(searchFor);
if (foundIndex > -1)
{
    cmbAnimals.SelectedIndex = foundIndex;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{searchFor} not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time, it success with my but with another way, and I will try this also.
Thank you :)